# Beautiful soup find_all() method is grabbing more tags than filter specifies

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following xml,

```
<url>
     <loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>
     <lastmod>2019-04-11T00:01:42-04:00</lastmod>
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
     <image:image>
         <image:loc> http://some-imageurl.com
         </image:loc>
         <image:title>GIFTS</image:title>
         <image:caption>quirky caption</image:caption>
     </image:image>
</url>
```

and I am attempting to extract just the "loc" tags.

I have used the following code to do this 
`products_list = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "loc")`
and I have tried using `soup.find_all(re.compile("\\bloc\\b"))` yet when I return this array result I have the loc tag as well as image:loc tag in the results (along with those tags text of course). Does anyone know beautiful soup is grabbing image:loc even when I specify that I want an exact string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes you are using Beautiful Soup 4.7+.

You can actually use selectors to target this. What you are showing looks to be XML, so I'm assuming somewhere in your document `image` is defined namespace.  For the sake of this example, we'll assume the namespace is defined as `xmlns:image="http://somenamespace.com"` which means the `image` prefix (what comes before the `:`) represents the `http://somenamespace.com` namespace. We are going to assume that the `loc` without has no namespace. Lastly, we'll use the `|loc` to specify we want the `loc` without a namespace:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:image="http://somenamespace.com">
<url>
     <loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>
     <lastmod>2019-04-11T00:01:42-04:00</lastmod>
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
     <image:image>
         <image:loc> http://some-imageurl.com
         </image:loc>
         <image:title>GIFTS</image:title>
         <image:caption>quirky caption</image:caption>
     </image:image>
</url>
</root>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

print(soup.select('|loc'))
```

Output

```
[<loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>]
```

---

But if `loc` has a namespace that is not assigned a prefix, we can still target it. Let's assume it has the default namespace of `xmlns="http://default.com"`. The loc we want isn't assigned a prefix, so in this example, it will inherit our default namespace.

Prefix in the document only really matter to the parser, so we can give our target namespace an arbitrary prefix name for our selector to use, we'll call it `default`. Then we can target the `loc` tag with `default|loc`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://default.com" xmlns:image="http://somenamespace.com">
<url>
     <loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>
     <lastmod>2019-04-11T00:01:42-04:00</lastmod>
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
     <image:image>
         <image:loc> http://some-imageurl.com
         </image:loc>
         <image:title>GIFTS</image:title>
         <image:caption>quirky caption</image:caption>
     </image:image>
</url>
</root>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

print(soup.select('default|loc', namespaces={'default': 'http://default.com'}))
```

Output

```
[<loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>]
```

You could even define it as the default namespace without a prefix, and then just target it as `loc`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://default.com" xmlns:image="http://somenamespace.com">
<url>
     <loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>
     <lastmod>2019-04-11T00:01:42-04:00</lastmod>
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
     <image:image>
         <image:loc> http://some-imageurl.com
         </image:loc>
         <image:title>GIFTS</image:title>
         <image:caption>quirky caption</image:caption>
     </image:image>
</url>
</root>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

print(soup.select('loc', namespaces={'': 'http://default.com'}))
```

Output

```
[<loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>]
```

---

For those not wanting to use selectors, you can also check the `prefix` of an element. In this case we want the `loc` without a prefix:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
xml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://default.com" xmlns:image="http://somenamespace.com">
<url>
     <loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>
     <lastmod>2019-04-11T00:01:42-04:00</lastmod>
     <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
     <image:image>
         <image:loc> http://some-imageurl.com
         </image:loc>
         <image:title>GIFTS</image:title>
         <image:caption>quirky caption</image:caption>
     </image:image>
</url>
</root>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')

print([el for el in soup.find_all('loc') if not el.prefix])
```

Comment: I haven't got it to work yet and I am still trying to wrap my head around why .select() would work on xml but I will keep exploring your solution. From what I can see, select() uses the soup sieve library which seems to be a css selector library

Comment: My namespace is http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 as well and none of the urls contain that domain

Comment: I just went perusing around on the internet and came across your github with soup sieve documentation. I tried the |* to force use of default namespace and was still unsuccessful. At least I understand the whole xml namespace issue and reasoning now though

Comment: CSS selectors can be applied to other document types. Not all things really translate over to XML, like HTML specific pseudo-classes, but there is nothing keeping them from working. Also, keep in mind XHMTL is XML and HTML, and selectors work there as well. Namespaces were carried over into HTML5 as well, albeit usually without prefixes and implied. And yes, soup sieve is the library, and I'm the author of it.

Comment: `|*` will select tags without a namespace. I can't see your whole document, so I don't know if it has a default or not.  If a default namespace is applied to your elements, and you tell the CSS selector what the default is (by feeding in the namespaces parameter with the default key being an empty string) you can target the default namespace with no `|` by default. This is based on the CSS specification.

Comment: I've updated with an alternative solution that uses no selectors and instead simply looks at the returned elements from `find_all` and checks for the one without a prefix.

Comment: @facelessuser - Your alternative solution seems to work even if it doesn't check for a prefix (i.e., without `if not el.prefix`). Is that supposed to be the case?

Comment: thank you so much @facelessuser. The updated solution checking for tags without a namespace prefix works

Comment: @JackFleeting In my testing, removing `if not el.prefix` gave me the tag with the prefix and the tag without. I'm using bs4 4.7.1. I'm not sure what version of lxml I'm using though.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed with this setup and my output is: `[<loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>]`

First i load a file with your strings inside. However I had to make some corrections: 
File: test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <url xmlns:image=" ">
        <loc>https://mystore.com/products-t-shirt.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2019 - 04 - 11
        T00: 01:42 - 04: 00
        </lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <image: image="">
        <image loc="">http://some-imageurl.com
        </image>
        <image: title="">GIFTS</image:>
        <image: caption="">quirky caption</image:>
        </image:>
    </url>
```

and here the code in python

```
import bs4 as BS

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with open("test.xml", "r") as f:
        xml = f.read()
    soup = BS.BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")
    tag_selection = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "loc")
    print(tag_selection)
```

As you can see in the output the only string retrieved is the loc tag only.

I hope it helps

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately I have tried that and haven't got it to work

Comment: I based my answer on your code, indeed; the very different thing is about the xml itself. In my IDE it appeared filled with errors. You could solve it importing the xml part and applying some str().replace("string a", "string b"). For example: str(xml_text).replace(":image", ":image=\" \""). Hope it's helpful. However the other answer (not tested by me) seems, at reading, right and useful

Comment: I have a scheduled meeting with a friend to attend to but I'll look into the other solution a bit further when I get home. I tried what he/she showed in their last suggestion and I received an empty array so no matches whatsoever. the code for that looked like this product_list = soup.select('loc', namespaces={'':'http://www.sitemaps.org'}) there is an http : / / in there as well. SO just doesn't want to show it